# Is there (in jpos) any convertor which convert ISO message from one verion to another version?

Tags: java, iso, jpos

I want to convert iso message version from 1987 to 1993 and vice versa using jpos.
Is there any convertor present in jpos for it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no automatic way to do that in jpos, you should choose the iso87 version of the packager for the incoming side, and the iso93 version of the packager for the outgoing side.

But you will have to map fields according to the specifications of each of the interfaces.

If you are going to have more than two interfaces using different iso8583 specs I suggest you to read and implement [jpos-CMF](http://jpos.org/blog/2009/08/jpos-cmf/), and map your incoming messages to the CMF definition, and all your outgoing messages from that. I won't lie to you it's a lot of effort going field by field, but is the only way, there's no magically way to map every possible implementation of version 83 to every possible implementation of version 93, as there's no automatic way to do such mapping between two different systems using the same iso83 version but handling fields differently, for example the private ones.

Hope this point you in the right direction of what to do.